# Can't find Windows in my Grub BootLoader

Tags: linux, windows, boot, grub, bootloader

I installed Kali Linux next to Windows in dual boot mode, then I updated Kali. After rebooting my laptop to return to windows, it does not appear as an option in the grub boot loader anymore, even though I still can see Windows data when I go back to kali.

[image]

How do I restore Windows as a boot option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

edited: seems i am right, kali grub updated on 2022-06-16 to v2.06.
i searched on https://pkg.kali.org/pkg/grub2, it shows:

```
[2022-06-16] grub2 2.06-3kali1 migrated to kali-rolling (Sophie Brun)
[2022-06-15] Accepted grub2 2.06-3kali1 (source) into kali-dev (Sophie Brun)
[2021-08-10] grub2 2.04-20kali1 migrated to kali-rolling (Sophie Brun)
[2021-08-10] Accepted grub2 2.04-20kali1 (source) into kali-dev (Sophie Brun)
```

---

Here is the original answer:

What's your grub version? i guess should be >= 2.06, because after grub 2.06 version, os-prober is disabled by default.

To have grub-mkconfig search for other installed systems and automatically add them to the menu, install the `os-prober` (maybe kali already intalled) package and mount the partitions from which the other systems boot. Then re-run `grub-mkconfig`. If you get the following output: `Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions`, then edit `/etc/default/grub` and add/uncomment:

`GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false`

Then try again.

Also, there a setting in Windows 8/10 called "Hiberboot", "Hybrid Boot" or "Fast Boot" can prevent the Windows partition from being mounted, so grub-mkconfig will not find a Windows install. Disabling Hiberboot in Windows will allow it to be added to the GRUB menu.

---

links:
https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2021-December/041769.html
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GRUB#Detecting_other_operating_systems

Comment: Hello sir test92995, You helped me, thank you so much,
I got the same error and I added that line you gave me and it works, you are a lifesaver thanks again.